# Cannot recognize casting class during compilation

Tags: java, class, methods, casting

As you can see my student class is a subclass of person. I have used the standard .equals() method in the person super class. In my .equals() for the child class Student I am getting an error on third line of the method where I cast a new Student object from "other". The error reads "Cannot find Symbol" and occurs on this line Student newStudent = Student(other);
                                                          ^
Why is the symbol not recognized?

```
public class Student extends Person {
private double avgGPA;
private int gtID;
private String[] classes;

public Student(String name, int age, String hometown, int gtID, double avgGPA, String[] classes){
    super(name,age,hometown);
    this.avgGPA = avgGPA;
    this.gtID = gtID;
    this.classes = classes;
}
public double getAvgGPA(){
    return avgGPA;
}
public String[] getClasses(){
    return classes;
}
public int getGTID(){
    return gtID;
}
public String toString(){
    return super.toString() + " with gtid " + gtID;
}
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if (super.equals(other)){
        Student newStudent = Student(other);
        if (this.avgGPA != newStudent.avgGPA){
            return false;
        } else if ( this.gtID != newStudent.gtID){
            return false;
        } else if ( this.classes.length != newStudent.classes.length){
            return false;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.classes.length; i++) {
                if (this.classes[i] != newStudent.classes[i]){
                    return false;
                }else {
                    return true;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The correct syntax for a cast is: Student newStudent = (Student) other;

Comment: It thinks you're trying to invoke a method.

Comment: @BladeCoder thanks Ill try that out